# Unable to install CuPy 12.2.0 on Google Colab

Tags: installation, cuda, google-colaboratory, setup.py, cupy

I want to use CuPy 12.2.0 on Colab, but the default CuPy version installed on Colab is 11.0.0.
I tried several ways to install version 12.2.0, all of which failed.

1. When I tried to install cupy with the command, `pip install cupy-cuda12x`, and import cupy as `import cupy`, I received the following message.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cupy/_environment.py:447: UserWarning: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CuPy may not function correctly because multiple CuPy packages are installed
  in your environment:

    cupy-cuda11x, cupy-cuda12x

  Follow these steps to resolve this issue:

    1. For all packages listed above, run the following command to remove all
       existing CuPy installations:

         $ pip uninstall <package_name>

      If you previously installed CuPy via conda, also run the following:

         $ conda uninstall cupy

    2. Install the appropriate CuPy package.
       Refer to the Installation Guide for detailed instructions.

         https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  warnings.warn(f'''
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cupy/__init__.py in <module>
     16 try:
---> 17     from cupy import _core  # NOQA
     18 except ImportError as exc:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cupy/_core/__init__.py in <module>
      2 
----> 3 from cupy._core import core  # NOQA
      4 from cupy._core import fusion  # NOQA

ImportError: libcudart.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-329ec5cf1bc8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import cupy

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cupy/__init__.py in <module>
     17     from cupy import _core  # NOQA
     18 except ImportError as exc:
---> 19     raise ImportError(f'''
     20 ================================================================
     21 {_environment._diagnose_import_error()}

ImportError: 
================================================================
Failed to import CuPy.

If you installed CuPy via wheels (cupy-cudaXXX or cupy-rocm-X-X), make sure that the package matches with the version of CUDA or ROCm installed.

On Linux, you may need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable depending on how you installed CUDA/ROCm.
On Windows, try setting CUDA_PATH environment variable.

Check the Installation Guide for details:
  https://docs.cupy.dev/en/latest/install.html

Original error:
  ImportError: libcudart.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
================================================================


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seemed I need to uninstall cupy-cuda11x, so I uninstalled it as `pip uninstall cupy-cuda11x`.
Then I tried to import cupy again as

```
import cupy
cupy.arange(3)
```

I received a different error message,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0a93c279befd> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import cupy
----> 2 cupy.arange(3)

AttributeError: module 'cupy' has no attribute 'arange'
```

which is like, the cupy module is empty.

As for the CUDA compatibility, the CUDA version of Colab is 11.8, which is compatible with CuPy 12.2.

```
>>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

---

2. When I tried to install cupy with the command, `pip install cupy`, I received the following error message.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: cupy
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for cupy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cupy
  Running setup.py clean for cupy
Failed to build cupy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cupy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

At this point, I had no idea how I could fix it.

---

3. When I tried to install cupy with the following as recommended,

```
pip install chainer
curl https://colab.chainer.org/install | sh -
```

I just received the following error message and I gave up. The runtime type was selected as T4 GPU.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1553  100  1553    0     0  12757      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 12834
********************************************************************************
CUDA version could not be detected!
Try installing Chainer manually by: pip install chainer
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: "When I tried to install cupy with the command, `pip install cupy-cuda12x` [...] [T]he CUDA version of Colab is 11.8, which is compatible with CuPy 12.2." Yes they are compatible, but the `12x` in the command is the CUDA version, not the CuPy version. See the [table on their website](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/install.html#installing-cupy-from-pypi).

Answer (score 1):

CuPy is installed on Google Colab by default, so you can just `import cupy`. If you prefer the latest version of CuPy, try `pip install -U cupy-cuda11x`.